# Create a product's property table dependent on type

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm creating app on Laravel 5 and bumped with a problem.
I am trying to create product's properties, which are dependent on property type (integer, string, boolean).

There is a 'products' table:

- id - int, pk, ai, uns
- name - string
- code - string
- price - float null

'properties' table:

- id - int, pk, ai, uns
- name - string
- code - string

Product model code:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class);
    }
}
```

Property model code:

```
class Property extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
    public function integers()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(PropertyInteger::class, 'property_type', 'product_property');
    }
    public function strings()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(PropertyString::class, 'property_type', 'product_property');
    }
}
```

PropertyInteger code (ProductString code is the same):

```
class PropertyInteger extends Model
{
    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Property::class, 'property_type', 'product_property');
    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to get all properties and their values for product:
   (new App\Product)->with(['properties', 'properties.integers', 'properties.strings']);
and I'm getting all properties than belongs to Product model, but in values I'm getting all values for all properties.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your relational data model should be revised to something like:

```
Produts:
id - int, pk, ai, uns
name - string
code - string
price - float null

Properties:
id - int, fk(Products(id)), uns
pnum - short, ai(by id), uns
name - string
code - string
- pk(id, pnum)
```

I made up the syntax to describe the following relationships:  `Properties` should have a compound primary key `(id, pnum)` where `id` is a foreign key to `Products` (via `id`).  If only one property per type is allowed for a given product, then `pnum` could be a small integer representing type (you may even want a separate definitional table just for clarity.

To get a result set that matches Properties to Products you would carry out either an inner join (if you want to omit Products with no Properties) or a left outer join with Products as the left side table.  In either case the join predicate would be `Products.id = Properties.id`.

Ergo -

```
select
    ...
from
    Products
        inner join   <-- or left outer join if wanting to include propertyless products
    Properties
        on (Products.id = Properties.id)
where
    ...
```

Comment: 1 product can have many properties and it's not a problem and works. But product can have many values and some of them integers, some of them strings and booleans. The problem is in different data types.
If I have 1 data type "hasManyThrough" relation can beat my problem. But there are 3 data types